# Use sed to edit a value within quotes

Tags: regex, bash, replace, sed, double-quotes

xI have a text in this form:

```
foo1   bar1   xId "myId1";yId "something"
foo2   bar2   xId "myId2";yId "something"
foo2   bar2   yId "something";xId "myId3"
```

How can I use sed to edit the myId field? I want to append a value before it, like this:

```
foo1   bar1   xId "prefix_myId1";yId "something";
foo2   bar2   xId "prefix_myId2";yId "something";
foo2   bar2   yId "something";xId "prefix_myId2";
```

I cannot use awk because xId is not always in the same place in my file. However, it is guaranteed that the line is in this format:
someStuff  xId "myContent"; someOtherStuff

Thanks a lot, I can use

```
sed 's/\(.*xId \)[^ ]*\(;.*\)/ a \1"newValue"\2/'
```

but it replaces the contents by newValue instead of prefixing it...

The capture group should make use of xId

EDITED TO SHOW TRICKY PART, THANKS FOR YOUR COMMENTS

Comment: EDIT: can't use awk, not sed

Comment: `Can't use sed because xId is not always in the same place in my file` then try to provide a more representative input sample

Comment: Then post your solution with detail in answer section for others too see and also accept that solution.

Comment: is xId "myId1" fixed, meaning xId " fixed that's important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
 sed -r 's/(xId\s*[^"]*")([^"]*)/\1prefix_\2/' input.txt
```

I'm using two capturing groups: `([^"]*")` catches everything after the `xId` before the next opening `"` including them. `([^"]*)` selects the content between the `"`.

In the replacement pattern I reassemble the groups and inject the term `prefix_`.

Comment: It is nice, but it misses the 'xId' group. Some of my data is in the form `foo2   bar2   yId "something";xId "myId2";` and should turn into `foo2   bar2   yId "something";xId "prefix_myId2";`
I did not conceive this file, this small format change is very annoying...

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Nice one! This syntax was driving me insane.

Comment: @CyrilCros If you are almost going insane with the pattern already, I suggest to use `-r`. It simplifies the pattern a bit, and that's why it helps to keep the overview.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/\([[:space:];]xId[[:space:]]\{1,\}"\)/\1prefix_/' YourFile
```

will prefix your string content based on your structure assuming

- xld is not the first field without space before
- there is no `xld "` in string before your field name

Comment: The first assumption is not correct, unfortunately.
My file has lines like this:

`foo2   bar2   yId "something";zId "annoyingField";xId "prefix_myId2";`

I simplified my example...

Comment: i adapt the separator class in reply